# Sub-Sorting a group in mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I have this collection in mongo :

```
[
  {
    "key": "guitar",
    "name": "john"
  },
  {
    "key": "guitar",
    "name": "paul"
  },
  {
    "key": "guitar",
    "name": "george"
  },
  {
    "key": "drums",
    "name": "ringo"
  }
]
```

I want to group by "key"  first in ascending order and sort each group by name (descending order).

I've tried this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$key",
      "projects": {
        "$addToSet": "$$ROOT"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "projects.key": 1,
      "projects.name": -1
    }
  },
  
])
```

But it doesn't sort the `name` in the `guitar` group  :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "drums",
    "count": 1,
    "projects": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
        "key": "drums",
        "name": "ringo"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "guitar",
    "count": 3,
    "projects": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
        "key": "guitar",
        "name": "john" // ?????????????????????????
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
        "key": "guitar",
        "name": "paul"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
        "key": "guitar",
        "name": "george"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Question:**

How can I sort the group item's name?
Live demo: https://mongoplayground.net/p/nXaN76HzLV0

Comment: What should be the expected output then ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee drums , guitar ...... and in guitar group : I expect to see paul,john,george. ( names in desc order)

Comment: Why are sorting by `"project.key"` again as the key is bound to be same, just sort by `"project.name"`

Comment: I want first to see "drums" and then "guitar" . that's why i'm sorting by key

Comment: Its currently in the same order you specified right

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. can you please post a fix in the demo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `$addToSet` it will change the order of array value that we have sorted first, and you can't order array value without unwind (deconstruct array) it, you can try,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$key",
      "projects": { 
        "$addToSet": {
          name: "$name",
          key: "$key"
        } 
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$projects" },
  { $sort: { "projects.name": -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      projects: { $push: "$projects" },
      count: { $first: "$count" }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "_id": 1 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MZuH_7pG3t0)

---

If you are using `$push` instead of `$addToSet` then this will work,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { name: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$key",
      "projects": { "$push": "$$ROOT" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "_id": 1 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DYDuvqkeKdO)

---

> Difference between `$push` and `$addToSet`, `$addToSet` will replace value if its already in array set *(in your case $$ROOT will always be unique)* and will not maintain order of document, `$push` will add all value even if its duplicate but in order.

Comment: Thanks. what's unwind  actually doing ? it's not clear from the docs.

Comment: $unwind will deconstruct array and add all array documents in root

Comment: $$ROOT is unique so $addToSet won't replace anything. The only difference with $push in this case is that it messes with order of items.

Comment: @AlexBlex you are right, $$ROOT is always unique, i am correcting that.